# .NET Inject Behavior on Event Firing

Tags: .net, design-patterns

So I have an Method that I want to be called every time a Certain Object, in this case a `Form` has a specific event fired, in this case `FormClosing`. Now what I could do is create a `MyForm` that inherits `Form` and then does what I need it to something like

```
//Not Sure if this is 100% how you would do this but you get the idea
private void formClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod(this);
    RaiseEvent MyFormClosing;
}
```

However, what if I don't want to have to do the above. Is there some framework or pattern that would basically let me inject the behavior that want into code?

If this isn't clear enough I can explain more.

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to the event?

Comment: @Haplo, that's not really what I'm asking, this isn't just for one object. It'd be for all of the objects inherited from a base type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would adding a property that you can set to true or false to the MyForm class be enough to tell it not to call the method? Personally I would override the Closing method rather than subscribe to the event.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if(CallMyMethod)
   {
       MyMethod(this);
   }

   base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

If MyMethod is external to the form you can instead use delegates (maybe better naming as well)

```
public Action<Form> MyMethod { get; set; }
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if(MyMethod != null)
   {
       MyMethod(this);
   }

   base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

but really since it is a form, if you wanted to call an external method it would be better to subscribe to the Forms Closing event.

** OP Edit **

This was close enough to get me to where I wanted to go which was creating a partial class that inherited from `Form` and overriding the events there to do what I wanted.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using a base class. Basically I want to be able to inject that kind of behavior into the Default `Form` Class.

Comment: this actually got me to where I wanted to go. I edited in what I did into your answer